# sql server: what's wrong with my date data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have a column with dates, but it is a varchar:

```
8/31/2010 9:48
8/31/2010 9:49
8/31/2010 9:51
8/31/2010 9:52
8/31/2010 9:55
8/31/2010 9:59
8/31/2010 10:11
8/31/2010 10:13
8/31/2010 10:16
8/31/2010 10:37
8/31/2010 10:42
```

i made sure that none of these will be a BAD date:

```
SELECT *
FROM qcvalues.dbo.batchinfo
WHERE ISDATE(reporttime) <> 1
```

this returned 0 results

question:
i need to return dates between a certain range:

```
select rowid from qcvalues.dbo.batchinfo where CONVERT(DATE, Substring( reporttime, 1, LEN(reporttime)), 103)
    between cast('2010-08-01' as datetime) and CAST('2010-08-31' as datetime)
```

and i am getting this error;

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

what is wrong with my conversion?

Comment: why are you using the substring function from 1 to the length of the string?  did you intend to cut it off at the space delimiter?

Comment: you also might be able to get away with a straight string comparison without converting anything to dates (reporttime > '8/1/2010' and reporttime < '8/31/2010')

Comment: whoever put 101 instead of 103 was right but they deleted their answer

Comment: Why are you using DATE in the first part and DATETIME in the BETWEEN phrase? Not that it matters, but consistency is nice.

Comment: @Beth That is incorrect. Try this: `select case when '8/20/2010' between '8/2/2010' and '8/3/2010' then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: Yeah, it depends on whether or not he's always using a leading zero in the day of month section.  I think someone else suggested he stores the dates as yyyymmdd, which also could help.

Comment: @Beth - storing the dates as string is a mistake in any case. They should be stored as date, smalldatetime, or datetime, whichever is appropriate. Would you store dollar amounts in a varchar field, even padded with leading zeroes? I hope not.

Comment: @Beth - Actually, your new assertion is also incorrect: `select case when '11/20/2010' between '01/20/2010' and '01/20/2011' then 1 else 0 end` The only time it would work is in yyyymmdd format. Which as I said is still a big mistake.

Comment: He may not have a choice- this could be an input file he can't control.  In any case, I said he 'might' be able to get away with it.  It depends on what the input looks like.  For a monthly extract, which is what we deal with a lot, he'd be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
select rowid
from qcvalues.dbo.batchinfo
where
   CONVERT(DATE, reporttime, 101) >= '20100801'
   -- style 101, not 103
   -- also notice date conversion invariant format YYYYMMDD with no separators
   AND CONVERT(DATE, reporttime, 101) < '20100901'
   -- using BETWEEN with an end date of '8/31/2010' will skip
   --   times between '8/31/2010 00:00:00.003' and '8/31/2010 23:59:59.997'
```

Try this to see what the problem is:

```
select convert(datetime, '8/31/2010 9:48', 103)
select convert(datetime, '8/31/2010 9:48', 101)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to store dates then use a datetime column in the future

does this work?

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,RTRIM(reporttime))
BETWEEN '2010-08-01' and '2010-08-31'
```

If not use SET DATEFORMAT MDY before running it

And if you have to store it in a varchar column then use YYYYMMDD format...that way you can do

`WHERE reporttime like '201008%'`  if you want August 2010

Comment: +1,000,000 **If you need to store dates then use a datetime column in the future**

Answer (score 1):

put SET DATEFORMAT MDY before your query.

Comment: Wow, really? But it's no rival to the Oracle's to_date function. We need this function in our realm. Because, I'm always like... is this date 121 or 112 or even 104?

Answer (score 0):

Remember, this `CAST('2010-08-31' as datetime)`  will have its time portion as `00:00`.

Consider casting your varchar data as smalldatetime, and being specific about the boundaries of times in your between. No need to be converting, substring, etc. Just one `CAST` will do.

Consider this as a potential solution:

```
SELECT rowid from qcvalues.dbo.batchinfo 
WHERE CAST(reporttime as smalldatetime)
BETWEEN '2010-08-01' AND '2010-08-31 23:59'
```

Comment: personally, I like reporttime >= '2010-08-01' and reporttime < '2010-09-01' better than between.

Answer (score 0):

This will strip out the time portion too

```
select rowid 
    from qcvalues.dbo.batchinfo 

    Where cast(floor(cast(cast(reportTime as datetime)as float))as datetime)

     between    cast('2010-08-01' as datetime)
     and        cast('2010-08-31' as datetime)
```